# BaseInputConnection commitText voice input 2 times

Tags: android, input, voice

I extends BaseInputConnection and override commitText,But every voice input enter 2 times,How can I solve this problem?Thanks.

```
    @Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN;

    return new MyInputConnection(this, false);
}

public class MyInputConnection extends BaseInputConnection{
    public MyInputConnection(View target, boolean mutable) {
        super(target, mutable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition) {
                Log.v("voice input", text.toString());
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Why are you extending BaseInputConnection?  What type of app are you trying to write?

Comment: I want to change input method input characters sent directly to the computer, don't let it show in the Edittext.

Comment: I think you'd be better off subclassing edit text to just not draw the text to the screen, by overriding setText to save the string in a different variable.